# Delphi PrintDialog PaperSize is resetting

Tags: delphi, printing

To simplify my problem - lets assume I have 2 windows printer installed - one for A4 and one A3 (default papersize for that printer). Different driver.
When I open the tPrinterDialog with the A4 printer preselected and choose in the combobox (within of the dialog) the A3 printer then the A3 printer is resetting in most cases and shows A4 as papersize.

How can I avoid this?
This problems seems to appear at least in Delphi XE8, 10.1

```
var
  lPrinterIndexOld  : integer;
  lPrinterIndexNew  : integer;
  lOK               : boolean ;
  lPrintDialog      : TPrintDialog;
begin
  lPrinterIndexOld := Printer.Printers.IndexOf( MyPrinterName );
  Printer.PrinterIndex := lPrinterIndexOld;

  lPrintDialog := TPrintDialog.Create( nil );
  Result := lPrintDialog.Execute;
  lPrintDialog.Free;
  lPrinterIndexNew := Printer.PrinterIndex;
end;
```

lPrinterIndexNew has the properties of lPrinterIndexOld (for instance A4) - even if the Printer[ lPrinterIndexNew ] was defined in windows as A3

Edit: 
Since it seemed to be not clear enough I try to explain it better:
Depending on the situation the user want to print on A4, A3, A2 ... Every printer supports A4. Some A3 and for larger PaperSize you have in generally a plotter. Lets assume that the I have defined in windows and in the appliction several printer (A4, A3) (by name so I can find the printerindex and set the printer to save the user time). 
If the user preselects the right printer in the application then it works fine (and I could theoretically skip the printerdialog) But the users want to control settings (and also not waste paper).
If the user preselected the wrong printer and wishes to change it **within of the printerdialog** then the PaperSize and other settings of the preselected printer will be taken over to the new printer. This means that the A3-printer prints suddenly on A4 (except the user remembers to change this before printing in the printer dialog).
This is causing problems and the users wish that this behaviour has to be changed. Now my question was whether this is possible (without to create my own printerdialog)

Some users even reported that the tray was changed - which can cause even more problems.

Edit2:
tPrinterSetupDialog seems to be the better way. It is not perfect but is behaving much better (for my purpose).

Comment: Firstly you don't state whether this is VCL or FireMonkey. Secondly you seem to want to change how a print dialog behaves when you change the printer. For most (if not all) A3 printers, it is valid to print A4 and I think it is a legitimate assumption that that is what a user will want to do unless they specify otherwise.

Comment: It is VCL. And the user defined the printer as A3. If i set Printer.PrinterIndex := lPrinterIndexNew before opening the PrintDialog then it shows A3. Only if the programm opens an A4 printer and the user wants to change to the A3 printer then the papersize is not setted to A3 (within of the printer dialog)

Comment: Yes, but why would you assume that just because a user chooses to use an A3 printer that they would want to print A3 size? It may just be the printer sitting next to them and may have A4 paper in it. Imagine you were designing the print dialog (or any dialog) yourself. When you show modal you would set up your default values, let the user change them, and when they press OK pass the values back to the caller. That is exactly how this dialog works. The VCL modal dialog is just a wrapper for the windows dialog. That leaves you very little control over how it behaves.

Comment: I cannot understand this at all. Could you explain it a bit more clearly.

Comment: @dsm In the askers case, it is safe to assume if both A4 and A3 printers available they select A3 if they want A3 print - if they wanted A4 they'd select the A4 printer. Based on the question it is a legitimate problem. I don't know the answer, but it's legitimate. :)

Comment: I edited my original post and hope that this is now clearer. @Admiral Noise Bottom - yes, this is what I meant. Users should easily be able to swap between A4- and A3-printer and 24"- and 36"-plotters. Office-programs or the Acrobat Reader have no problem with that and behave as I wish. (but they dont use the printerdialog)

Comment: I have no clue how to achieve what you want but these two links might be useful. They are old but might help you. http://lists.elists.org/pipermail/delphi/1999-November/003972.html and this http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/how-to-set-printer-paper-size.html

Comment: I know how to set printer size. My problem is that after the dialog is closed I am not sure whether the user wants to print A3 on the A3-printer or whether he changed purposely to A4.

Comment: If I override the settings then there is no need to even enter the dialog - i could simply offer a combobox to choose the printer (~index). In most cases your document has a size - so it is clear whether you want to print on A4 or another papersize. But in my case these are technical drawings and depending on papersize & scale all will be printed on one page or it will printed out in "poster mode".